# french numbering on tikz graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, numbering, french

would you how can I display French numbers on charts created in tikz?

By default, only English numbers appear, even with the babel package and SIunit's Group-separator.

Comment: Welcome. // Please add a simple example, which compiles. Search for and try package babel.